DatagridView carga lento su DataSource C# y convertirlo en async devuelve InvalidOperationException: opracion no válida a través de subprocesos
Estoy tengo un datagriview que a partir de 5000 registros comienza una carga lenta usando datasource. He estado viendo ejmplos para usar asincronia, pero no he logrado separarlo en un hilo.
intenté usando esta cargar
datagrid.DataSource=losdatos.ToListAsync();// pero al aparecer no está disponible según fuentes desde el 2023 la biblioteca de Entity ya no tiene el ToListAsync();
intenté usando Task pero al cargarlo recibo esto:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operación no válida a través de
subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control 'dgv_lista_personas' desde un
subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó.'

Leí que usando backgroundWorker según esta documentación Cómo realizar llamadas seguras para subprocesos a controles (Windows Forms .NET)
De acuerdo a esa información con ese control se soluciona para un segundo hilo, pero no he tenido exito.
Me podrían dar alguna documentación por favor o que puedo usar para que el form no se trabé cuando carga los registros. Gracias.
Esto es lo que he probado, donde si carga, pero el programa se bloquea hasta terminar de cargar los registros
esto no funciona porque sigue trabándose el programa:
private async void CargarDatosAsincrono()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Cargar los datos en segundo plano
            var datos = ObtenerDatos();

            // Actualizar el DataGridView en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario
            BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                dgv_lista.DataSource = datos;
            }));
        });
    }

esto tampoco funciona, sigue trabándose el programa
private async void CargarDatosAsincrono()
        {
            var datos = await Task.Run(() => ObtenerDatos());

            // Actualizar el DataGridView en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario
            Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                dgv_lista.DataSource = datos;
            }));
        }


//aquí llamo los datos
 private object ObtenerDatos()
        {
            
            return objApis.datos();
        }

SEGUNDO EDIT:
Capa presentación
  //Evento que inicia el proceso de la carga
        private async void btn_cargar_lista_personas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                await objApis.SolicitudGetPersonaCN(dgv_lista);
    }

Capa Negocios
//Llamada de la implementación de la solicitud Get
        public async Task SolicitudGetPersonaCN(DataGridView dgv_lista)
        {
            await objGetAPI_DAO.SolicitudGetPersonas(dgv_lista);
        }

Capa Datos
     //Solicitud GET para obtener la lista de las personas registradas
            public async Task SolicitudGetPersonas(DataGridView dgv_lista)
            {
                try
                {
                   //... por aquí Código que no relaciona al llenado
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    HttpResponseMessage respuesta = await ... la api);
    
                    if (respuesta.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                string respuestaJson = await respuesta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    
    //Aquí llamó al metodo LoadData1() enviándole la lista de los objetos devuelvo en el JSON para que llene y devuelva un DataTable 
    
               Persona[] listaPersonas= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Persona>>(respuestaJson).ToArray();

                    dgv_lista.DataSource= await LoadData1(listaPersonas);

  //... por aquí más Código solo unos labels globales que asigno el total de los resultado nada que bloque el programa
                   }
    
                }
    
              }
    
    //Método que devuelve objeto DataTable lleno
    
         public Task<DataTable> LoadData1(Persona[] personas)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NombreColumna", typeof(string)));
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NombreColumna", typeof(string)));
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NombreColumna", typeof(string)));
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NombreColumna", typeof(string)));
                    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NombreColumna", typeof(string)));
        
        
                    return Task.Run(() => {
                        foreach (var row in personas)
                        {
                            dt.Rows.Add(row.NombreColumna,row.NombreColumna...más columnas);
                        }
                        return dt;
                    });
                }

Esto lo hice basándome en estos ejemplos https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/asynchronous-programming-in-C-Sharp-5-0-part-5-access-data-sing/  pero se sigue bloqueando el programa cuando carga la lista, me interesa mucho solucionar el menos esto, el tiempo que demora no lo considero muy crítico, pero que se bloque es muy malo creo.
También ya intenté hacer estos ejemplos que se ven muy completos, pero me ocasionan el primer error mencionado sobre que no se tuvo acceso al control
https://grantwinney.com/using-async-await-and-task-to-keep-the-winforms-ui-more-responsive/
También probé intentando crear el task en la capa presentación pensando que tal vez no logra acceder por la capa en la que se crea el Task, pero fue el mismo resultado de que no se tuvo acceso al control, añadiendo como información extra recientemente intenté utilizar un label para informar el estado de una tarea en un Task, pero tuve el mismo error con el label, lo que me hace deducir que este problema no es particular a un datagridview sino a cualquier control, pero entonces que hago para que cuando cargue el data gridview no se trabe el programa, la verdad por el tiempo de carga no importa tanto, pero si considero muy crítico que un programa se cuelgue en algún proceso, reconozco que me falta mucho por aprender, pero tampoco quiero dar por terminado este proyecto con este problema de que se trabe o bloque en la carga. Gracias.

Deberias cargar tu viewmodel a traves de un subproceso que haga las lecturas asincronicas.. decis que lo probaste, pero sin ver que hiciste dificil ayudarte mas....

Hola, he puesto lo que he intentado. Sin éxito

5000 datos no son problema para un DataGridView (a menos que tengas una gran cantidad de columnas), así que tienes algo que está demorando el proceso. Usar funciones asíncronas no hará la carga más rápida, lo que hará es que la interfaz gráfica no quede colgada mientras carga (pero el tiempo de carga será más o menos el mismo). En general, cargar un DataGridView es un proceso de varios pasos, desde obtener los datos hasta renderizarlo en la UI, debes completar tu pregunta y mostrar esos pasos

Es que te falta un monton de cosas.. mira esta respuesta que di.. no tenes que usar task.run, tenes que usar todas funciones asincronicas, sin necesidad de eso... tu grilla deberia usar un esquema mvvm, donde no necesitas aclararle el source a cada rato, solo le tenes que pasar la referencia al view model y usar INotification... mira esta respuesta

@Yussef Muchas gracias por responder, si pudieras revisar ahora lo que se hace para cargar el datagriview y señalarme mis errores estaré muy agradecido contigo.

@gbianchi Hola, listo, agregué el procedimiento de lo que quiero lograr. Gracias por responder.

@José Te falta agregar una parte que es importante. Supongo que recibes un JSON, como y con que librería lo estas desrealizando? también mostrar como estas leyendo el contenido de la respuesta respuesta.Content._____?

@Yussef Gracias por responder, ya agregué, pero creo saber porque lo mencionas, pues veras no es la respuesta, ya hice varias pruebas, haciendo que por ejemplo en lugar de llenar el datagridview en ese método de la solicitud GET solo guardo el array y después se hace la llamada con otro método, pero el resultado es el mismo, ya me tiene algo cansado, he intentando muchas cosas, mover el llenado a la capa presentación o a la capa de negocios, pero sigue bloqueándose el programa. si tienes un canal y si tienes algún tutorial para estos casos lo veré, porque creo que no hay y me suscribo jejej.

@Yussef utilizo esta librería  y con este ejemplo para colecciones https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm

@José Hice una prueba con el código de tu "Segundo edit", cargué 5.000 datos de forma instantánea, luego probé con 50.000 e igualmente fue instantaneo Luego al api le agregué un delay de 10 segundos. Ahí, evidentemente demoró en cargar 10s, pero en ningún momento se colgó la UI

La respuesta que te pase hace exactametne lo que pedis.. que parte no te sirivio??? y usar dt ya esta totalmente desactualizado.. si queres mas velocidad todavia, usa un ORM...

@Yussef Gracias, veré que puedo hacer, es extraño que a ti no se te bloque el programa mientras se llena el datagridview y a mi si con la misma lógica.  Por cierto actualicé a solo .Net la otra noche y quedó bien. Si pones tu código como respuesta la pondré como solución a esta publicación amigo. Saludos.
